# Get timer event in parent class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, timer, mfc

I have MFC form `InputYesNoDlg` that is derived from `CDialogExInput`. In `CDialogExInput` I have added timer. Unfortunatly I can't get timer event when I create `InputYesNoDlg` form. Why?

Code `CDialogExInput`

**h:**

```
#define ID_INPUT_TIMER 101
...
afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT uTime);
...
```

**cpp:**

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDialogExInput, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CDialogExInput::OnTimer(UINT uTime)
{
    timeElapsedSec--;
}

BOOL CDialogExInput::OnInitDialog()
{
    SetTimer(ID_INPUT_TIMER,1000,NULL);
    return true;
}
```

Code `InputYesNoDlg`

**cpp:**

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(InputYesNoDlg, CDialogExInput)
...
    BOOL InputYesNoDlg::OnInitDialog()
    {

     return CDialogExInput::OnInitDialog();

    }

...
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can't get timer event"?  Do you have your own OnTimer in InputYesNoDlg?  Do you expect it to behave like a virtual (it's not - it's just a method in CDialogExInput that is hooked in CDialogExInput's message map).  Or is the CDialogExInput's OnTimer not firing? Or ???

Comment: I expect to get call to void CDialogExInput::OnTimer(UINT uTime). What I need to do to get it there?

Comment: I noticed you were missing the chainback call in `CDialogExInput::OnInitDialog()` to (I assume) `CDialog::OnInitDialog();`

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong in the code you have shown.